# JavaFX, изменение объектов внутри лямбды

Tags: java, ооп, javafx

Есть такой слушатель на слайдер, но почему я не могу изменять(переприсваивать) переменные которые существуют вне функции?

```
mySlider.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue,newValue) -> {
    myobj = something.getMyObj();            
});
```

Comment: Можете, если они объявлены глобально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компилятор преобразовывает лямбды в анонимные классы. Эти классы могут менять поля объемлющего объекта или других объектов, на которые имеют ссылки. Но передаваемые в лямбды локальные переменные должны быть неизменяемыми, так как замыкания в Java эмулируются созданием в анонимном классе поля, захватывающего значение замыкаемой переменной. Убедиться в этом просто. Скомпилируем класс

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String value = "Test";
        Supplier<String> lambda = () -> value;
    }
}
```

и запустим с параметром `-Djdk.internal.lambda.dumpProxyClasses=.`, чтобы Java сохранила сгенерированный анонимный класс. Заглянем внутрь этого класса

```
$ javap -p Main$$Lambda$1

final class Main$$Lambda$1 implements java.util.function.Supplier {
  private final java.lang.String arg$1;  // Захваченная переменная value
  private Main$$Lambda$1(java.lang.String);
  private static java.util.function.Supplier get$Lambda(java.lang.String);
  public java.lang.Object get();
}
```

Об этом можно почитать у Брайана Гетца в "[State of the Lambda: Variable capture](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html)".