# Почему в анонимных классах помимо своих переменных можно использовать только финальные переменные

Tags: java

Почему в анонимных классах помимо своих переменных можно использовать только финальные переменные(в случае лямбд эффективно финальные), чем обусловлено такое ограничение?

Comment: [И на ту же тему про лямбды.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/807606/204271)