# Использование переменной в методе equals в лямбда-выражении

Tags: java, lambda, лямбда-выражение

Можно ли как-то реализовать сравнение строк в лямбда-выражении при условии, что одна из строк - это переменная?
Хочу сделать DAO интерфейс с методом find, который принимал бы лямбда-выражение. Что-то вроде этого `object -> object.getValue().equals(variable)`. Но IDE ругается, говорит, что переменные должны быть `final` или просто не должны меняться в коде.

Comment: Переменные использовать можно. А вот меняться после объявления лямбды, они, действительно, не должны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лямбды - это элемент функционального программирования, а в функциональном программировании любую проблему можно решить применением функции высшего порядка:

```
Function<String, Predicate<String>> f = v -> s -> s.equals(v);

String variable = "Hello";
Predicate<String> p = f.apply(variable);

System.out.println(p.test("Hello"));
System.out.println(p.test("World"));
```

Comment: То есть каждый раз мы должны создавать новый предикат?

Comment: Каждый раз, когда изменяется значение переменной. Ну или можно вместо переменной хранить значение в поле, тогда функция-фабрика не нужна будет.

Comment: Новое поле - исключено. А с фабрикой, как по мне, код получается не очень читабельным.
Дааа... Теперь мне кажется, что это была глупая затея :)

Comment: А зачем нужна функция высшего порядка, если можно взять готовую функцию двух аргументов: BiFunction<String, String, Boolean> bf = (s1, s2) -> (s1.equals(s2)) ?

Comment: @Андрей автору вопроса нужна лямбда принимающая один аргумент.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev да вроде бы он 2 строки хотел сравнить... ну ладно в общем

Comment: @Андрей корень проблемы и суть вопроса, как я их понял, в [особенностях работы замыканий в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/807606/204271), а не в способах сравнения строк.

Comment: Интересно, а как вы считаете, что если создать класс-обертку со статическим полем типа String и в лямбду передавать именно его?
Например:
`Wrapper.string = "some value";
dao.find(object -> object.getValue().equals(Wrapper.string));

Wrapper.string = "some another value";`

Comment: @Jajavar в однопоточном коде - это просто архитектурно плохое решение, а в многопоточном вовсе непозволительное.